# How to solve assertion failure on GPUImage after device rotation?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

The following code block works well and adds a blurred view to itself from another view.
However, after the device is rotated, any call to "update", triggers `Assertion Failure: GPUImageFramebuffer.m:269`

`"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?"`

I couldn't find the reason. Removing and revreating GPUImageView does not help. What am I doing wrong?

```
GPUImageiOSBlurFilter *blurFilter=[[GPUImageiOSBlurFilter alloc]init];
blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 3.0f;

self.gImageView=[[GPUImageView alloc]init];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

self.gpuImageUIElement =[[GPUImageUIElement alloc]initWithView:(appDelegate.mainViewController).baseholder.view];
[_gpuImageUIElement addTarget:blurFilter];
[blurFilter addTarget:_gImageView];
_gImageView.frame=self.view.frame;
_gImageView.alpha=0.01;
[self.view insertSubview:_gImageView atIndex:0];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [_gpuImageUIElement update];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            _gImageView.alpha=1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
    });

});
```

Comment: That's an interesting one. Right now, I release input framebuffers after they've been rendered to the screen, but on rotation you'll need to re-render those. I may need to change how views in particular handle their incoming framebuffers.

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you Brad for GPUImage, great work! I am new to GPUImage; how can I re-render those?